# If you have a focus for your spell casting do you need to pay materials?

Tags: dnd-5e, spell-components, spellcasting-focus

In D&D 5E, if you have a focus (like bards have instruments and clerics have holy symbols) for your spell casting do you need to pay for materials?

Answer (score 19):

### Sometimes.

(PHB p.203, "Components") Your focus can only replace some of your material components. Specifically, components with a listed value are *not* substituted by the focus.

For example, if you wish to cast *control water* with its material component of "a drop of water and a pinch of dust" your focus will suffice. But if you wish to cast *continual flame* with its material component of "ruby dust worth 50gp, which the spell consumes" you need to provide that material component separately.

(It's worth noting that not all price-specified components are consumed during spellcasting: compare *continual flame* with something like *Drawmij's instant summons.* Priced components which are not consumed are still not substituted by a focus, though.)

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that many DMs will make you simply deduct the gold cost from your inventory, and not required you to actually have the item.  Yes, it's a house rule, but it's a fairly common one, and makes book keeping easier

Comment: It is common (as are all modifications designed to not play the inventory/encumbrance game), but it's one I, personally, dislike and I won't be including. I think it'd make perfectly good sense to post a second answer describing whatever scheme you use, though =)